# Dealing with being bullied in Scrum meetings

Tags: united-kingdom

I have recently graduated university and joined a company, as such I am the most junior member of the software team.

For the past few months or so during SCRUM scoring sessions other members of the team have relentlessly mocked me for the way I display a 3 when scoring (the way I display it is different to the rest of the team).

The meaning of "displaying a 3" in the context of a SCRUM scoring session is to show the number 3 with your fingers.  For example:
[image: Their Way] versus [image: My Way]

How can I get the other team members to stop mocking me as it is heavily affecting my confidence and is making me reluctant to score 3s in our scoring meetings?

Maybe relevant that I'm also the only African member of the team and at times other team members have mocked my pronunciation of some English words, and I feel this may be more evidence the rest of the team don't respect me.

Solutions I don't want to try

- Scoring a 3 the "normal" way (this way hurts my hand)
- Using a device to show my scores in Scrum poker (This will make me
  stick out even more)

I don't necessarily want to escalate to HR or above our scrum team, but if this continues I feel I have no choice but to take this higher in the company

Comment: Assuming you're talking about holding up fingers I would strategically combine two on the left hand with one on the right. But perhaps that's not the most diplomatic option and it would only work if this "bullying" isn't mean spirited. Do you get the impression they're just messing around or do you truly have a bad relationship with your colleagues or concerns over racists motivations?

Comment: What re the seniority of these team members? Are they also graduates and on their first job? Is your manager aware of this?

Comment: @Lilienthal Yes I am talking about how I display a "3" with my fingers. I don't think they are racist as we are all members of the same race

Comment: Have you brought this up during a retrospective or mentioned it to your Scrum Master by the way? Those are the two normal starting approaches.

Comment: This is a toxic work environment. In the UK there are laws against this kind of thing, but we will need more specifics about the nature of the mocking to offer advice.

Comment: @SandraK, from the description, it sounds like OP is talking about Planning Poker, which is a popular method for estimating work for Scrum teams. For each task being considered, each member of the team votes by showing a number indicating how complex they think a task will be. If there is a wide variance in how the team members vote, further discussion is held until they reach a consensus. Once each task has an agreed number, the team can plan what tasks they will commit to complete next.

Comment: Do the team members mock other members too for different things? Or is it *just* you?

Answer (score 12):

Maybe I come from a different environment where these jokes are just considered stupid but they do not denote a lack of respect.

Maybe I consider diversity (mine and of the others) amusing and lovely (my wife, and now our son, displays number "in a different way").

Can't you take it with some humor? Seriously. Pun intended.

If that really bothers you then you should talk to THEM. Do not involve HR, do not talk with Scrum Master. Don't be confrontational if you are willing to have friends with another and **different culture** (which you just started to know and maybe to appreciate). Next time they do it simply state "it was funny, first two times, but now I feel like a tiger in a zoo. However, if you want to improve yourself, I can teach you to count this way".

Do not overthink and don't feel bulled, they're just having some low price fun. Did you ever think they may think it's "soooo cuuuute"? Don't assume the worse, you may be favorably surprised.

Comment: About the humorous point: try to make a "three", using your thumb, your index, and your smallest finger, so it looks like the sign of the devil (don't forget to smile when you do it) :-)

Comment: @Dominique I do it every time I go to a Metal concert! :) Let's post our attempt to make it using thumb and last two fingers...

Comment: @Dominique With the thumb in, it's actually a sign to ward off the devil (evil eye). Metal fans call it 'the horns'. With the thumb out, it means "I love you".

Comment: @Belle-Sophie Does it mean "I love you"? Ahahah in Italy we use it to say "your SO is cheating on you"! Ahahhahaha

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti with the thumb out, it does in the US and in the UK some people (at least I do) would recognize it as such as well. That’s hilarious though! Bottom line, OP beware of cultural differences!

Answer (score 6):

You can:

1. ignore it - they will forget at some point

or

2. react with self-confidence. To give you an example, every time we go bowling with any team, my team starts making fun of me. They claim I bowl differently and I probably do although I can't really explain it. I tell them I don't bowl differently, I bowl better than they do. Or later when we talk about favorite sports I stress how I love bowling. 
   I don't know what "scoring 3s" means so I can't give you a more precise advice. But maybe try to "score a 3" in such an exaggerated way that they know you're being self-deprecating. Sing it, make a victory gesture after showing it, thank them for an opportunity to deliver a 3, whatever. It's just about them being surprised and feeling it's stupid to attach so much attention to how someone delivers a 3, it doesn't need to make sense. When you make fun of it yourself you show them you don't care about them making fun of it and they will stop.

Avoid taking it too seriously or in racial terms. It's just not serious enough unless they offend you or abuse verbally. Everybody experiences things like that. Such things will happen all your professional life and if you attach too much attention to them you will be frustrated a lot.

Comment: 1. Is often advised, but usually doesn't work at all.

Comment: I know some people who are masters in this strategy. They just smile and wait showing the others they don't care. I really admire that. Personally I find 2. faster and more rewarding.

Comment: You might want to watch the movie "Inglorious Basterds". One of the major plot points was based on the fact that Brits and Germans tend to show the number "3" using different fingers.

Comment: I now googled it. It's funny cause I'm from Western Europe but I would always show "3" the British/US way.

Comment: But I would think the people are laughing because of the reference to Inglorious Bastards and not because... they are inglorious bastards. I wouldn't treat it as bulling unless there's some info scrumGrad didn't include in the first comment.

Comment: Oh My...Google! In Italy we count as in Germany...I always thought everyone in the west count this way! It's time to prove they're wrong.

Comment: I agree with this answer and upvoted, but the mocking of the OP's "three" gesture might very well be a manifestation of a far more severe problem of disrespect. OP should refrain from escalation for now because he might really need to go to management, later on, for more serious transgressions.

Comment: @Toss thanks for the answer and advice, but not sure why you mentioned "racial terms" Could you clarify?

Comment: As far as I remember you wrote about racial differences in the first version of your post, which you seem to have edited in the meantime.

Comment: You can check the edit history, no mention of race in my posts

Answer (score 0):

This is regarding bullying/discrimination, so the usual applies: Document all instances. If all goes well you won't ever need the documentation - but it's necessary for worst case prevention.

---

The issue you describe is an impediment, raise it with your Scrum Master. One of the many ways the Scrum Master can resolve the specific "3" problem is to distribute cards and insist on using them - arguments for cards over hands are that you're not limited to numbers between 0 and 10, "?" will show more often, and laying them on the table face down reduces peer pressure. The SM should also be able to at least improve your overall situation by using  the various tools they have at their disposal - which range from the trivial (e.g. scheduling a team lunch) to the extreme (e.g. removing a person from the team) with plenty of options in between.

If the Scrum Master is the one mocking you, see if you have friendly HR which you can ask for actual advice, without starting the corporate HR complaint machinery. They may have more insight into the characteristics and motivations of the people involved, so may be able to provide better advice. This has a risk of misfiring badly, because different HR departments can approach things quite differently. So make sure you have a solid paper-trail in place before you contact HR.

---

If you want to deal with the bullying directly on your own, the idea is to deflect their attack, and by jabbing back with a friendly attack give them the opportunity to turn it into harmless banter.

When they mock the way you show "3", mock them right back: "Ah, you're so jealous." (there are better comebacks, but this is a useful general purpose one) - At this point they can chose (A) to give up, (B) to continue the banter, or (C) to escalate into attack mode. If they chose (C) you won't be able to work with them on the long term, so you'll need to document each and every instance with excessive precision, then contact a lawyer, and only then contact HR.

Comment: Related response, "What? You can't make a 3 like this?" with a disbelieving tone of voice.

Answer (score 0):

Give a quick heads up to the scrum master about what's going on so he or she knows what's coming.

The next time you want to score a "3" you say "Bully #1, how do you score a 3? " Then you ask "Bully #2, how do you score a 3?" And finally: "This is how I score a 3, and if anyone has a problem with it, they are welcome to go to HR about it".

Comment: That seems to be a pretty nuclear option. Threatening people with HR is seldom going to make a good team. Going to the Scrum master is a good idea, but basically going over his head threatening people is not.

Comment: You are not saying you are going to HR. You are saying that anyone who has a problem with the way you show a "3" is welcome to go to HR about it (and show themselves as a fool), meanwhile you do what you want and they should shut up about it.

Comment: @nvoigt This isn't a good team though. It can possibly become one if they get rid of their childish behaviours. This just might do the trick. It is simple, easy and gets the point across no doubt. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a cultural difference, which your teammates are making fun of.

You mention this has been going on over the 'past few months', so I assume this happens every time you hold up your fingers that way instead of they way they do.

I also suspect, since you say it's been going on for 'months', that they have not let off on it either.

And since I assume your team leader is present at the scrum, they also have implicit approval to be doing this, or they would've been asked to stop already.

So you have two options here:

1: Address it directly with your teammates or supervisor.
2: Accept their teasing and hope that it will become a non-noteworthy discrepancy in the future.

If it is truly bothering you and making you feel less confident in your work, you should definitely take option 2 - consult your co-workers first, and let them know that you don't appreciate this treatment.  Be courteous - they might not even realize how badly this has affected you.  Only consult your supervisor if the behavior continues after you've addressed your co-workers yourself.

If you don't feel like this is affecting your workflow however, and if you feel that it could pass over time, you might want to just ignore it.  Some casual teasing is common in any setting, even the workplace. As long as it is not persistent, discriminatory (which IS a concern here, mostly for your inexperience and cultural background), or detrimental to work, you could consider letting it pass.  But that is your own decision.

Importantly, it does not matter if you decide to let it pass for awhile, and then decide to take action later if it is apparent they will not let up.  A problem in the workplace that continues to be a problem doesn't have a statute of limitations - so you should go about this at a pace that is comfortable to you.

Answer (score -3):

I personally feel when it comes to bullying, and I say this from experience, the ONLY truly effective way to deal with it is to STAND UP TO THEM. They will crumble before your eyes. For eg. if they mock your pronunciation, find something about them to mock ruthlessly. I know many would say this is not a mature, professional way to deal with them - but remember, you are not dealing with mature, professionals here.

Reporting them to HR is about as useful as a chocolate teapot - it will only serve to incite the bullies more, and they will retaliate. If you make further complaints, YOU will become the problem in HR's eyes.

But also, you need to find ways to have commonality with other members of the group/workplace even if it is just polite small talk. Are you isolating yourself at the moment, because sometimes the isolation alone can make you an easy target for bullies

Comment: This might "work" but it will almost certainly trigger the side-effect of being seen as somewhat unlikable by that group. This effect isn't as much of a problem with schoolyard bullies, but in a workplace it might be a very bad idea.

Answer (score -5):

1. I suggest @JeffO's excellent comment: don't let it show that it bothers you.
2. Workplace bullying is a very common thing. Don't believe, that is has no reason. It has a reason, but this reason can't be said directly. Most likely you won't ever know it, **but it has**.
3. Companies ruled by such evil guys won't live too long. A healthy workplace community helps you and catalizes the work, and not suppresses its workers. It has, or it will surely have other symptoms, what you can't see. But finally they will get their punishment, only not from you.
4. Most likely they are also actively working on your firing in the background.
5. It is quite possible that they will reach this goal.
6. Try to not worry on that. Fight until the last shot, and **do your best in the work until the last shot.**
7. If you will be fired, leave in peace from your side, and try to make this little episode so peacefully, as you can.
8. **Talk about it with some boss or similar!** While they are eating you, they will commit mistakes. They will have surely unfair, easily disprovable arguments and so on. Point to their mistakes, these are strong arguments for you! However, even if this boss side with you, it won't surely defend your job. First, because not always he is the only boss by the company, and second, because he can't fire everybody only because they all hate you.

Unfortunately, you need strong nerves now. Your chances are bad to survive this story with a stable position in your job, but this gives you the best chances for that. And this is what the so-named "professionalism" also wants from you.

As I can see, it is your first workplace. Don't worry on that, you will have a lot later in your active life. Don't worry on that it would be a "bad start in your life". No, it won't have any bad effect on your moral, on your CV and on your carrer in the long term.

Check the CV of others on different job portals. You will see, that a short first work is not some "uncommon" thing, or a "stigma", no. It is a pattern.

A year later you will laugh on these bastards working still on that crap and still defending their trash from the incomers.

As a precautive maneuver, you can also silently start to find other jobs. Young IT professionals are very popular on the job market. You have a weapon, a strong weapon in your hands: you can say "enough" and accept a new offer. But commit this "treason" only if the bosses don't side with you. If they side, then fight until the last shot.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The OP is the target of a **collective workplace bullying**. What I am seriously thinking, that I need to make my formulations more polite. But I don't think that a workplace bullying should be judged essentially lighter.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I polished the terminology on your first two example. The third ("change job") doesn't exist in the post.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Furthermore, my suggestion would be to you to refrain [ad hominem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem) arguments. 1) they are not nice 2) they are irrelevant.

Comment: I hope you did not find my rethoric question offensive, it wasn't my intention. I was specially surprised for the strong feelings emerging from your post and I had to ask if YOU had an especially bad experience. You're right, "change job" isn't literal. Correct text is "start to find another job". I suppose we read question from opposite points of view, where I see stupid jokes (possibly even positive) you see workplace group bullying. Points of view, it's healthy for the OP to read them both. I don't think you have been rude...just...surprisingly extreme.

Comment: Sorry, but this contains *way* too many assumptions and some of the advice is just impractical. -1